# Greece Corfu and Gerald Durrell sites - how can be reached?

Tags: greece

What is the current situation with Gerald Durrell's Corfu described in his famous book " My Family and Other Animals"? In childhood it was one of my favourite  books. I was green with envy of his child life on Corfu and wanted to change places with him. And to add fuel to the fire there was also that film on TV - [My family and other animals](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0q8-3lsS_qE). Anyway childhood is gone, but desire to see and show to my children Durrell's Corfu is still here (or what is left from it).

What I would like to visit are Durrell's house (houses) and places where they lived. Did places change much? Mega "Hilton" hotels or still wild sceneries?

EDIT: BTW How Corfu can be reached? It is convenient for me to fly to Athens from Moscow, since there is no direct flight to Kerkira. What is the cheapest way to reach Kerkira, assuming that it surely be ferry, because of rented car.

Comment: At the risk that not many people might have read the book, maybe you want to describe closer what exactly you are expecting from a trip to Corfu?

Comment: @uncovery I'm going to edit my post to clarify it little bit. The question is from "Saint Petersburg of Dostoevsky" category. So without reading the book it's hard to tell about expectations, since all of them are very subjective.

Comment: I think you ask two questions in one: (1) how to visit the sites and (2) how to get from Moscow to Korfu. Better to split?

Comment: @nikita Like Marcel suggested, please split your question into two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was in Corfu in 1995, so this is not the most up-to-date information. As far as I know there are no "The Corfu of Gerald Durrell" tours, but nothing to stop you going and seeing the places where he lived and wrote about. The best known is "The White House", which was a private residence when I was there and could be viewed but not visited. According to [this article](http://www.independent.co.uk/travel/europe/my-family-and-durrells-corfu-jane-horrocks-explores-the-naturalists-mediterranean-island-7939781.html) it is now a Taverna. That article is actually very helpful and will giv eyou an idea of what to expect. It also lists some direct flights to Corfu from the UK.

Comment: Thanks! Article is good, though I'm going to fly from Moscow, not UK.

Answer (score 3):

During the summer period, there are direct connections (charter flights) i.e. [www.tez-tour.com](http://www.tez-tour.com), or [www.kanoulastravel.com](http://www.kanoulastravel.com) from Moscow to Corfu.
Alternatively you can fly to Athens and Drive to Corfu, or Bari and catch the Ferry to Igoumenitsa or Corfu [www.onferry.com](http://www.onferry.com).

Certaintly Corfu has changed a lot since Durrell's times, but if you step off the holiday resorts, it is easy to identify the "wild " side of Corfu he wrote about. Corfu is quite large island and has many untouched areas, it is a UNESCO protected site, and the Vast olive grouves have remaind unchanged.

There are also some day trips, "on the steps of Durrell", showing one of the places he lived in and a path across the coast

Answer (score 2):

The follow link will help you, there is a description of all Durrell-villas.
http://whitemetropolis.wordpress.com/2011/05/29/the-durrell-villas/